# findByIdAndUpdate Model and increment based off button click

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am simply trying to increment a Mongoose User model every time a button gets clicked in my dashboard.ejs and am running into trouble.  This is my first time creating express routes so any help would be great!

You can view the terminal error below.  I am only showing the method in the controller which I am working on right now, but the conrtoller file is actually much larger.

the req.user object is returning properly in the controller and returns the current user that is logged in

### userRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const controller = require('./userController');



router.route('/login')
  .get(controller.getLogin)
  .post(controller.postLogin)

router.route('/register')
  .get(controller.getRegister)
  .post(controller.postRegister)
router.route('/logout')
  .get(controller.getLogout)

router.route('/buyBullet')
  .get(controller.buyBullet);


module.exports = router;
```

### userController.js

```
exports.buyBullet = (req, res, next) => {

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $inc: { bullets: 1 }})
  User.save();
  console.log(req.user)
  res.redirect('/dashboard');

}
```

### dashboard.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header'); %>
<a href="/users/logout" class="btn btn-secondary">Logout</a>
<a href="/users/buyBullet" class="btn btn-warning">Buy Bullet</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Make Your Pick</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="https://www.nfl.com/schedules/" target="_blank">Schedule</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Rules</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Message Board</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Dashboard</h1>
      <p>The Date is now <b><%= new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'}).format(new Date()) %></b> 
        and the time is now <b><%= new Date().toLocaleTimeString() %></b></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

### error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/views"
    at Function.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/app.js:74:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
GET /users/buyBullet 500 60.356 ms - 2220
```

Comment: Well the error means you do not have a view named error.ejs in the views directory. So create it and the error should be gone. It also means there's another problem since express wants to render error view. I think that this `User.save();` might cause the error. `User` is instance of Model which doesn't have a `save` function. I don't  think you need it at all. Just add a callback function to `findByIdAndUpdate` and it should be fine. -> `User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $inc: { bullets: 1 }}, function(err, result){ // check for error or call res.redirect('/dashboard');})`

Comment: @Molda TY!!!!!!!!